# Disable shiftmode xamarin forms android navbar

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

If you have more than a certain number
Of icons the navbar bottom mode
Shows icon with no text and shifts the icon when selected
Is there an official fix for forms no renderer

If not I will take any fix

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an Android Problem, Xamarin is working on a fix in the next release, in the meanwhile, you can follow this gist, with code to prevent that:

https://gist.github.com/LynoDesu/64904b6d143892cf14a60a32798a36bb

Comment: Thanks for your time! I guess this will have todo. Hopefully it will be in next release!. I can wait provided it really is in next release. Do you happen to know how to track this one in particular?

Comment: Well, here is the link from the Xamarin Github Page https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1675